# Spring Boot Data Repository that maps from persistence layer to application layer

Tags: database, spring-boot, dao, data-representation

In my Spring Boot service, the data representation used in my database (persistence layer) is different to the representation used in my application logic.

I currently have a layer of services between the repository layer and business logic layer which handle mapping between the persistence layer and domain layer representations.

Does Spring provide a way to automatically handle this in the repository layer? The conversion is just two static methods which take an object and return it in the other representation.

Here is short example of my layers and my current solution. I can't post actual code but this demonstrates the issue. I can't change my data representations or the mapping code:

```java
@Service
public class UserService{
    @Autowired UserMapper mapper;
    @Autowired UserRepository repository;

    public UserEntity someServiceMethod(UserEntity entity){
        entity.setName("Billy");
        final Function<UserEntity, UserEntity> mapped = 
            mapper.mapped((dbUser -> repository.save(dbUser)));
        return mapped.apply(entity);
    }
}

@Service
public class UserMapper{
    private final Function<DbUser, UserEntity> toApplication = /*...*/;
    private final Function<UserEntity, DbUser> toPersistence = /*...*/;

    public Function<UserEntity, UserEntity> mapped(Function<DbUser, DbUser> func){
        return toPersistence.andThen(func).andThen(toApplication);
    }

    // + many more to deal with lists, no-argument repository methods etc.
}

@Repository public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<DBUser, Long>{}
```

Ideally I'd like to just be able to do something like

```java
@Repository public interface UserRepository extends CrudMappingRepository<DBUser, UserEntity, Long>{
    @Override protected final Function<DbUser, UserEntity> toApplication = /*...*/;
    @Override protected final Function<UserEntity, DbUser> toPersistence = /*...*/;
}
```

Comment: Could you pls post with your code?

Comment: Have added an example